# struck in this limits question

Tags: limits

Can you please solve this limits question

$$\lim _{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}         \frac{[\frac{x}{2}]}{\log(\sin x)}$$

Where [ . ] is the greatest integer function.
Options are a.0, b.1, c.-1, d. Doesn't exist

Comment: What have you tried? Have you even _tried_ putting in $x=\pi/2$? You are expected to show some effort yourself if you want people to put in effort to help you.

Comment: Sorry martin, but actually the question was typed wrong.

Comment: Is this the final form of the limit? You changed it after my answer, but my hint is still helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $0<\frac{\pi}{4}<1$ and $\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=1$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, but mistakenly I typed the question wrong. Can you please take a look at it again.

Comment: OK using 0<pi/4 <1, I got the upper part as zero, which makes the whole limit 0. But putting pi/2 in sinx the denominator also becomes 0. Which isn't possible. So my question is should I ignore the below part and simply  mark the answer as 0. Or is there a different way to handle that. Actually I am a bit weak in all this stuff.

Comment: The numerator of your function equals $0$ on some punctured neighborhood of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (i.e. $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\cup (\frac{\pi}{2},2)$), but the denominator is nonzero. Hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: How can the denominator is non zero. Can you please elaborate. When I put $\frac{\pi}{2}$ into the denominator log(1) also tends to zero, in the same neighborhood. Can you tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: To calculate the limit you don't put $\frac{\pi}{2}$ into the function, you need only points of some punctured neighborhood of that point. The denominator itself goes to zero, it is not equal to zero when $x \ne \frac{\pi}{2}$, but the numerator is equal.